# django cms in virtual directory

Tags: python, django, django-cms, virtual-directory

I'm developing a django web with django cms, and I want to put the django cms in a virtual directory, i.e., I have my main web in:

> localhost:8000/[pages]

and I want the django cms web in:

> localhost:8000/virtualdirectoryname/lang/[pages]

So, I tried to configure the urls.py with two files:

urls_cms.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^virtualdirectoryname/', include('project.urls_cms')),
    #... Definition of more urls from my main page
]
```

When I do this, I got the error:

> Using i18n_patterns in an included URLconf is not allowed

So, How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Django CMS will treat any url segment after / as the slug/path by which to look up a page. I doubt you'll be able to run a Django CMS project that way.